# Best in-game overlay for Skype, Steam, and web-browsing

Tags: web-browser, windows-8, skype, steam

I have trekked the internet for anything that I could possibly find, and have tried the following so far:

- Overwolf,
- Steam (of course)
- Origin In-Game
- EvolvE hq

And probably others, may have forgotten.

Anyways, I have found none of these to fulfill my wishes. My wishes are:

- Easy access to Skype chats and calls
- Steam chat and voice chat
- A good ingame browser

That's about it.

Overwolf was the best so far, but the Skype app is gone, and I can't play Steam games and Steam chat at the same time. Won't let me log into both. All of these features should be all-in-one, and I don't want multiple programs doing pretty much the same thing each with one used feature. That's just wrong.

Comment: who uses skype? use overwolf with teamspeak, or just use Steam chat/ voice

Comment: Now you can log into steam multiple times so that covers that but unfortunately yes the skype api for overwolf is gone... im hoping overwolf do find a way to bring it back i loved it... well that me kicking buckets so.... bye :P